# nacos discover port that matched management port not server port

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, nacos

I have set two ports in application.properties as follows:

```
server.port=8081
server.servlet.context-path=/open/api
management.port=8079
```

After the service started, visit [http://127.0.0.1:8080/nacos/v1/ns/instances?serviceName=[serviceId]](http://127.0.0.1:8080/nacos/v1/ns/instances?serviceName=%5BserviceId%5D), you can find the port value is 8079,

it must be 8081. Because my gateway is distributed through this nacos, if it is 8079,It will request my service with this management port. Can this be solved by modifying the configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following property set in your application.properties

```
spring.cloud.nacos.discovery.port=8081
```

This ensures that your server port (8081) is registered with Nacos instead of the management port (8079).